# How to send POST request with a cURL in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I need to send a POST request to Cloudflare API,
Their API example is:

```
curl -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/023e105f4ecef8ad9ca31a8372d0c353/purge_cache" \
     -H "X-Auth-Email: user@example.com" \
     -H "X-Auth-Key: c2547eb745079dac9320b638f5e225cf483cc5cfdda41" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     --data '{"purge_everything":true}
```

I have been trying from my functions.php file to make a POST request. Here is my code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'my_url' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'X-Auth-Email' => 'my_email',
            'X-Auth-Key' => 'cf_api_key',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        ));
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( '{"purge_everything":true}' ));
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

    var_dump($result);
```

I am getting this response

```
'''{"success":false,"errors":[{"code":9106,"message":"Missing X-Auth-Key, X-Auth-Email or Authorization headers"}]} bool(true) '''
```

Where and how should I put my X-Auth-Key etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use the array of httpheader as single values, separeted with doublepoint, not as key value pair:

please see this example:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'my_url' );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'X-Auth-Email: my_email',
            'X-Auth-Key: cf_api_key',
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ));
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["purge_everything"=>true] );
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

    var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.
Now I am getting this error:
`"{ "result": null, "success": false, "errors": [ { "code": 1012, "message": "Request must contain one of \"purge_everything\", \"files\", \"tags\", \"hosts\" or \"prefixes\"" } ], "messages": [] } " `

Comment: i have edit my answer, you can't use a json string and encode it as json string, in this case it is double encoded and produces wrong post data

Comment: I have also updated your code and now getting this only:

bool(false)

Form here what and how I can make it workable, any idea please?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I put static string 'my_url' instead of my real one. But after correcting my code I am still getting the same error
"{ "result": null, "success": false, "errors": [ { "code": 1012, "message": "Request must contain one of \"purge_everything\", \"files\", \"tags\", \"hosts\" or \"prefixes\"" } ], "messages": [] } " 

Btw, thank you so much for your help, if fact you have solved the bigger part of this.
Highly appreciated.

Comment: please mark as accepted answer, in case it helped you